# Neo4j cypher query poor performance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have these nodes:

1. `user{user_id}: users`
2. `thread{thread_id, published_date, like_count, comment_count, view_count}: posts`
3. `tag_id{tag_id}: the tag of the post`

And these relationships:

1. `(user) - [: FOLLOWED] -> (tag)` // the user follows the tag
2. `(thread) - [: BELONG_TO] -> (tag)` // the post belongs to tag
3. `(user) - [: READ] -> (thread)` // user reads the post

Now I want to query 5 posts belong to tag user follow user has not read that thread, and that thread must be up to date, order by point DESC. I created index on User(user_id), Tag(tag_id), Thread(thread_id) and i run this cypher query from the browser:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:FOLLOWED]->(t:Tag)<-[:BELONG_TO]-(th)
WHERE u.user_id = 3 AND NOT EXISTS((u)-[:READ]->(th))
WITH u.user_id AS user_id, th.thread_id AS thread_id,
t.tag_id AS tag_id,duration.inDays(datetime(),
datetime(th.published_date)).days AS days,
(0.5*th.like_count + 0.3*th.comment_count + 0.2*th.view_count) AS point
ORDER BY days DESC
RETURN DISTINCT thread_id SKIP 0 LIMIT 5
```

With just 1 node in database (also embedded ) took 235 ms. Obviously something is going wrong. What could be the problem. Pleace hepl me

Comment: Where did you run this query from: the browser? Code? If code, where did your code run? Seems like you're doing quite a bit there, especially since you're doing calculations inline in your query. I'm not sure there is anything "obvious" you're doing wrong, but... I would suggest editing your question to include more specifics, including how you benchmarked this.

Comment: thank @DavidMakogon I  edited my query

Answer (score 0):

In your MATCH you have a bi-directional pattern.

```
(t:Tag)<-[:BELONG_TO]->(th)
```

Do you have set an index or constraint on :User(user_id) ?

Comment: here only exists relationship ```(thread)-[BELONG_TO] ->(tag)``` but not relationship ```(tag)-[BELONG_TO]->(thread)```. I have set an index on :User(user_id), but it still handles it very quickly. What could be the problem. Pleace hepl me!

Comment: Clarifying questions should be comments under the question, not as part of an answer (which then creates a discussion under the answer, which is now happening here).

Comment: @Anh - please be sure to add any clarifications to the question itself, not tucked away as a comment here. Also, no need to insist that people help - that's the idea of the site.

Comment: I don't see any such bi-directional relationship pattern in the OP's query.